# Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova : Update NPM and NodeJS

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Hi I installed Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova during the winter.  I have now worked on an angular project which has npm dependancies, and gulp files which use a Node server to serve pages to test out the app.

I did however like the way VS.Net installed NodeJS and other tools during the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova installation, adding the correct paths to my system to get great CMD support for git, npm etc.

I want to continue to develop Cordova apps using Visual STudio, especially using the Mac remote deployment node module that was installed.  However I find that the version of NodeJS and NPM that was installed is now out of date.  I got a warning about version numbers when I installed the Azure-cli node package.

What is the best way to update NodeJS and NPM versions so that they stay integrated with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Comment: I also see that vs-mda-remote is now up to 0.2.11 and when I installed VS.Net Cordova it was 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific limitation for updating nodejs, but please be aware of some [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-general.md) related to newer version of nodejs. Just make sure you will not run into these scenarios, and I think you can feel free to update.

If you do encounter any issue after you update the nodejs to a specific version, I think it's good to raise the issue and let MS VS team to fix it in future release.

And make sure the nodejs is added into your PATH system environment varaibles.

Comment: So I would upgrade Node and NPM as instructed on their websites for windows as usual?  Where is best to notify the MS VS Cordova team, isn't it this stackoverflow forum?

Comment: Yes, follow the intruction on their site. To notify the MS VS Cordova team, you can feel free to post it on stackoverflow, because the team is closely monitoring questions with visual-studio-cordova tag. I am working in MS as well and currently helping the team to reply questions here together. You can also directly email the team. Check the information included in "more information" section on https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs#more-information.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  Just wanted to make sure.